# Prove or disprove that there is a element $y$ in $G$ such that , $y^2 = x$

Tags: group-theory

Let $(G,*)$ be a group. And let $ x$ be a element of odd order of $G$ , then prove or disprove that , there is a element $y$ in $G$ such that , $y^2 = x$

Please provide some hint, i am not able to show any contradicting examples nor able to prove it.

Comment: What examples of groups with elements of odd order have you tried?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang $ Z_n$

Comment: Good.  If you can prove the statement for $Z_n$, then you can prove it in general, because if $x$ has odd order, it generates a subgroup isomorphic to some $Z_n$ (where $n$ is odd).

Comment: @MatthewLeingang i didn't get it please could you elaborate

Comment: Yeah no it's your homework problem

Comment: @MatthewLeingang ok thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $x$ has order $2n+1$. Then $x^{n+1}$ can serve as $y$, since $y^2=x^{2n+2}=x^{2n+1}x=x$. Therefore the statement is true.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x^{2k-1} = e$ for some $k\ge 1$, then $x^{2k} = x$, then let $y=x^k$.

Comment: This is essentially the same as Parcly Taxel's answer with $k=n+1$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: If $y^2=x$ what is the relation between the order of $y$ and that of $x$?

Comment: Both have same order..i had tried this...but not able to find any disproving example